# How appropriate is the usage of Adjective "biweekly" when there is no noun like "biweek"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biweekly) dictionary, The word Biweekly is a noun as well as adjective (and even an adverb!).

I did intense research on internet but could not find answers to below questions:

**Questions**:

1. Is 'biweekly' an adjective of the noun 'biweekly' itself?
2. What are such nouns called which are the adjectives of themselves?
3. How will biweekly be used in following sentence: "I propose biweekly newsletter to be published ______" (one word for "Twice a week"-*biweekly?*, but it sounds weird)

Comment: The word is a derivation of the adjective *weekly* with the productive prefix *bi*. Simple as that. Also, you could say "I propose a biweekly newsletter" or "I propose a newsletter be published biweekly", either is fine and the word has the same meaning and role in each, but it's redundant (though grammatical) to say "I propose a biweekly newspaper be published biweekly"; what information is the extra "biweekly" adding for your audience?

Comment: A biweekly is published only biweekly. (The only problem is that biweekly can mean either *every two weeks* or  *twice a week*. The only way to resolve  this is to know how often a specific biweekly is published, and this can usually be found out on each edition.) A weekly is published weekly. A daily is published daily. Except I guess there could be 'special editions', but they would be labeled as such.

Comment: Biweekly is used to describe publications that are published both *twice a week* and publications that are published *every two weeks*. There is no 'one-word' that means a *twice-a-week biweekly*. That one word is biweekly. You just have to live with the ambiguity. It's the same for bimonthly. It can be irritating, but that's the way it goes.

Comment: See the video and usage note here at MW: http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/how-often-is-biweekly

Comment: The above link at MW suggests using *semiweekly* to mean *'twice-a-week biweekly'*, but I don't find that suggestion helpful, since *semi* often does not a have a precise meaning in terms of measurement: we  do something on a semi-regular basis means we do something on an irregular basis. So saying something is a *semiweekly* does nothing to clarify the issue.

Comment: People need to get over this ambiguity and learn what is correct. Biweekly, every two weeks; semi-weekly, twice a week.

Comment: @Unrelated - No. Every two weeks is "fortnightly". Unfortunately, despite the word "fortnight" being known in America, "fortnightly" appears not to be.

Comment: @Unrelated Alas, I fear the cause has long been lost.

Comment: I am pleased to report that *biweek* is a week set aside to celebrate bisexuality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1.

Biweekly is, in your terms, more likely to be a "noun of the adjective".

Generally, creating new words from other words is called **derivation**. Creating a new word by changing the word class of a word without any change in spelling specifically is called **conversion**. Creating a new word by attaching something to another word is called (derivational) **affixation**.

The two most likely orders of derivation are:

> (a) *week* (n.) -> *weekly* (adj./adv.) -> *biweekly* (adj./adv.) -> *biweekly* (n.)
>
> (b) *week* (n.) -> *weekly* (adj./adv.) -> *weekly* (n.) -> *biweekly* (n.)

Determining the order of derivation can be somewhat tricky, and giving a definitive answer is often impossible. However, it is generally assumed that more semantically complex lexemes are derived from the more simple ones.

Thus, the noun *weekly* ('something that appears weekly') was likely derived from the adjective/adverb *weekly* ('once a week'), as the former contains the latter in its meaning. Also, the result of attaching the suffix *-ly* is standardly an adjective or adverb, so going from *week* as a noun straight to *weekly* as a noun seems highly unlikely.

Therefore, *biweekly* is either the result of (a) conversion from *biweekly* (adj./adv.) or (b) affixation of *bi-* to *weekly* (n.). However, it's almost impossible to know which one it is.

Source: BA degree in English language & linguistics

### 2.

There is no specific term for nouns that are also used as adjectives, or the other way around. The process by which one word is derived from the other, however, is called **conversion**, as mentioned above.

### 3.

As pointed out in the comments to your question, either *I propose a biweekly newsletter* or *I propose a newsletter to be published biweekly* are fine. To avoid any confusion whether biweekly means twice a week or every two weeks, I would however suggest being maximally clear and saying *I propose a newsletter to be published twice a week*.

Comment: Now that's a solid EL&U answer.  I award you the "best new contributor who *gets it*" hat.  Wear it with pride. Also this +1.